# Получить ID ресурса по имени

Tags: android, java

Можно ли как-то получить ID ресурса из Java-кода, если известно только его имя (имя файла картинки)? То есть получить доступ к ресурсу, не обращаясь к R классу (`R.drawable.filename`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В классе Resources есть метод

```
public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

Используется так:

```
fragment.getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "drawable", "my.project.package");
```

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно, используя reflection.
Я делал так:

```
R.drawable.class.getField("name_of_the_resource").getInt(getResources())
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, нет. Все ресурсы должны быть обязательно определены в R классе.

Comment: Мои ресурсы определены в R классе (автоматически генерируются, если положить картинки в res/drawable). Мне интересна сама возможность обращения к ресурсам без обращения к R.

Comment: Ну, я и говорю. Они определены там, и нельзя к ним обращаться без обращения к R. (Насколько я знаю.)