# получение значения файла assets

Tags: android

Есть фотографии в папке assets. В папке ресурсы есть названия к каждой фотографии на разных языках. Глупый вопрос, где и каким образом хранится что к этой фотографии именно это название? Я изучал джаву на джавараш, там близкое для хранения ключа-значения был hushmap, здесь же все файлы в разных местах

Comment: Нигде, если Вы сами об этом не позаботились.

Comment: Видимо не так сформулировал. Мне и хотелось бы узнать, как об этом позаботиться

Comment: Ну например, можно так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/24935/11515 получить `id` строки с названием по имени ресурса, только вместо `drawable` соответственно `string` и использовать одинаковые имена для файла картинки и ресурса его названий.

Answer (score 2):

В class R не генерируется id файлов размещенные в папках assets, поэтому нет просто способа получить указатель на этот файл. Вам необходимо использовать путь -> String который подходит для ***AssetManager*** и использовать его для удобства, чтоб получить данные из этой папки. 
[AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager)

Для удобного использования и хранения String (путей) вы можете использовать любую удобную коллекцию, которые вы точно проходили в JavaRush. Но вам обязательно необходимо учитывать факт консистентности ваших путей до файлов, порой это не очень удобно.

В Android для изображений используют drawable папку, вы также можете решить легко проблему локализации, разрешений и других условий систем.